# Getting Permission error when renaming python

Tags: python, operating-system, renaming

I want to rename files and subdirectories with my python script.
simply replacing "." with spaces.

sample dir tree:

> .\fsdf.trsd.nf.g
>   .\beautifyer.py
>   .\lsWithSdir.py
>   .\fsdf.trsd.nf.g\fe.gre.asd
>   .\fsdf.trsd.nf.g\fa.tr.b.d.txt
>   .\fsdf.trsd.nf.g\fe.gre.asd\new.path
>   .\fsdf.trsd.nf.g\fe.gre.asd\New.Text.Document.txt

```
import os
from os.path import isdir

# prompt user for path
dirPath = input("enter path of dir where the files are\n")

# subs = input("do you want to include renaming for subdirectories? (y/n)\n")

# change to path
os.chdir(dirPath)


# replace spaces
def replace_spaces(file_name):
    new_name = file_name.replace(".", " ")
    return new_name

def checkType(filePath, file):
    if os.path.isdir(file):
        new_name = replace_spaces(file)
        os.rename(filePath, os.path.join(filePath , new_name))
    else:
        file_name, file_ext = os.path.splitext(file)
        new_name = replace_spaces(file_name)
        os.rename(filePath, os.path.join(filePath , new_name + file_ext))



def get_items(dirPath):
    for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(dirPath):
        for name in subdirs:
            file_path = os.path.join(path)
            # doStuff(file_path, name)
            print(file_path + " | " + name)
            checkType(file_path, name)
        for name in files:
            file_path = os.path.join(path)
            checkType(file_path, name)


get_items(dirPath)
```

Error:

> . | fsdf.trsd.nf.g
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File ".\beautifyer.py", line 41, in 
>       get_items(dirPath)
>     File ".\beautifyer.py", line 35, in get_items
>       checkType(file_path, name)
>     File ".\beautifyer.py", line 21, in checkType
>       os.rename(filePath, os.path.join(filePath , new_name))
>   PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: '.' -> '.\fsdf trsd nf g'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were sending wrong filepath to checkType function see the modified code as below:

```
import os
from os.path import isdir

# prompt user for path
dirPath = input("enter path of dir where the files are\n")

# replace spaces
def replace_spaces(file_name):
    new_name = file_name.replace(".", " ")
    return new_name

def checkType(filePath, file):
    if os.path.isdir(filePath):
        new_name = replace_spaces(file)
        os.rename(filePath, os.path.join(os.path.dirname(filePath) , new_name))
    else:
        file_name, file_ext = os.path.splitext(file)
        new_name = replace_spaces(file_name)
        os.rename(filePath, os.path.join(os.path.dirname( filePath) , new_name + file_ext))



def get_items(dirPath):
    for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(dirPath):
        for name in subdirs:
            file_path = os.path.join(path,name)
            # doStuff(file_path, name)
            print(file_path + " | " + name)
            checkType(file_path, name)
        for name in files:
            file_path = os.path.join(path, name)
            checkType(file_path, name)

get_items(dirPath)
```

Comment: This worked till folder "fe gre asd" where .\fsdf.trsd.nf.g\fe.gre.asd\new.path
.\fsdf.trsd.nf.g\fe.gre.asd\New.Text.Document.txt is inside. They still aren't renamed

Comment: If you debug the code you will find that you are just renaming last part of the path not the entire path if you want to rename entire folder path you have modify the  `checkType` function accordingly.